# 'Select All' Parameter not working

Tags: stored-procedures

Posted as a new question

The report is working ok in regards to selecting one country and seeing the different data within the 12 or 36 months date range.

The problem comes when I 'Select All' countries.  What I want is the totals of all the countries to be represented on the graphs.

this is what the output is

country        yyyy-mm      Population   Employed     12months      36months

```
  uk           2016-06        56            43           y             y
  france       2016-06        40            22           y             y
  Germany      2016-06        73            32           y             y
  uk           2015-06        45            10           n             y
  france       2015-06        30            11           n             y
  Germany      2015-06        76            56           n             y
   AND SO ON......
```

All help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Help me here to understand the scenario, you are planning to have 3 parameters - one for country one for date range (what sort of input will these have?) and the third for 12/36 months. Based on the selection you intend to display line charts.

Comment: It will be 2 parameters...one for country and the other parameter will be a choice of '12 months' and 36 months'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've described I think something like this will work for you

You are correct that you need two parameters: one for the country, the other is the period. For this second parameter specify two entries in the report designer. Give them the labels '12 months' and '36 months' and values or 12 and 36 respectively. Now change your dataset query as shown in the example below (obviously my table/column names won't be the same as yours)

```
select country, [yyyy-mm], Total
from @datatable
where country = @country
and ((@period = 12 and [12months] = 'Y') or (@period = 36 and [36months] = 'Y'));
```

The last line is where the magic happens. By testing the value of the @period parameter in the where clause we can make parts of the clause conditional.